# Crazy "String or binary data would be truncated" error with correct type and length

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with following table structure;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SALES](
    [COLUMN1] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [COLUMN2] [varchar](11) NOT NULL,
    [COLUMN3] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [COLUMN4] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [COLUMN5] [datetime] NULL,
    [COLUMN6] [datetime] NULL,
    [COLUMN7] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [COLUMN8] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [COLUMN9] [smallint] NULL,
    [COLUMN10] [smallint] NULL,
    [COLUMN11] [datetime] NULL,
    [COLUMN12] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [COLUMN13] [smallint] NULL,
    [COLUMN14] [varchar](20) NULL CONSTRAINT [DF__SALES_DATA__3F3D11FA]  DEFAULT (null),
    [COLUMN15] [smallint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_SALES_anonymous]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [COLUMN16] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [COLUMN17] [varchar](11) NULL,
    [COLUMN18] [smallint] NULL,
    [COLUMN19] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [COLUMN20] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [XPKSALES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[COLUMN1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

However, when I update the value with 11 characters into the COLUMN17 (Note that the column length is 11), the SQL Server throws following error. I am using SQL Server 2014.

> String or binary data would be truncated.

However, I have created a table with one column having a length of 11 characters and inserted value with 11 characters. It was successfully inserted, then update the same value. Update too success.

Can someone help me to identify the issue?

### UPDATE

For some reason, the only way to solve it was casting the value

```
UPDATE SALES SET Column17 = CAST( '89000107051' AS VARCHAR(11))
```

Can someone explain why was necessary to do that for a plain varchar value with the proper length?

Note: Triggers is not the answer

Comment: Are you sure it is throwing error on column17 and not on something else.

Comment: [SQL Server 2017 will finally banish this spectre](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4468101/), even though it still requires a trace flag. No help for those on earlier versions, though.

Comment: @SalmanA: Yes. double checked.

Comment: You might have unseen characters on the value you are inserting. Try doing LEN(Value).

Comment: Is there any trigger on your table?

Comment: @EzLo: No. There were no hidden characters, even space.

Comment: @DanielBrughera: There are 4 triggers associated with this table. Those are to record table activities such as insert, update, delete.

Comment: "There are 4 triggers associated with this table" case closed!

Comment: @nwGCham then disable the update one or check what its doing maybe adding some characters or inserting in other table with different length....

Comment: @DanielBrughera: Thanks for the tip. I have removed all associated trigger one by one. However, Still, I am getting the same error. :(

Comment: Can you post your update code??

Comment: update SALES set COLUMN17 = '89000107051' where COLUMN1 = '10001'

Comment: You can try forcing the CAST: UPDATE SALES SET Column17 = CAST( '89000107051' AS VARCHAR(11)) if it doesn't work is because there is something else massaging your update but nothing else than triggers come to my mind

Comment: Run a profiler trace to see what is going on.

Comment: @DanielBrughera : Absolutely awesome... Your suggestion is working perfectly..!! Thank you very much. Can you please add your comment where I can vote up ..??

Comment: @Greg: Thank you very much for your suggestion..!!

Comment: Update your question with the solution, maybe someone here can tell us why it was necessary for a plain varchar value

Comment: @DanielBrughera: Do you know the reason why it works for CAST?

Comment: It don't know the reason why it doesn't without it, for me is redundancy